# Sort on string representation of integer?

Tags: mysql

I have a bookmark table with a bookmark type field which has type int(11).

To sort my bookmarks by type i can execute a simple query:

```
select * from bookmarks order by type
```

Works great.

Except this sorts bookmarks by integer type.

In my gui i convert the integer type to a string representation:

```
1=Great
2=Bad
3=Wow
...
```

The above query results in:

```
bookmarks of type Great
bookmarks of type Bad
bookmarks of type Wow
```

because the bookmarks are sorted on integer type.

I would like to get the result:

```
bookmarks of type Bad
bookmarks of type Great
bookmarks of type Wow
```

How can i sort on the string representation of the integer type without changing the field type and not losing handy query features like pagination?

Comment: You can use FIND_IN_SET for that.

Comment: Why don't you just rearrange the numbers with respect to their string values? `1=Bad`, `2=Great`, and `3=Wow`.

Comment: You could make type(int) an fk to a table of [type | description] order by the former, select the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your order by to execute on the string not on the id:

```
select * from bookmarks
order by CASE
WHEN type = 1 THEN 'Great'
WHEN type = 2 THEN 'Bad'
WHEN type = 3 THEN 'Wow'
ELSE 'Zzz' END
```

Comment: Cheers, i gave it a shot and it works. I like this solution cause it doesn't require any database changes and very few changes in my code.

Answer (score 1):

The formal way will be to create a new types table that will be looks like this one:

**types**

```
id    type
1     Greate
2     Bad
3     Wow
```

Then inside the query you can do something like this:

```
Select *
From bookmarks inner join types
On bookmarks.type = types.id
Order By types.type
```